# Solr default core isn't created

Tags: solr, rubygems

I am trying to install [this project](https://github.com/mejackreed/leaflet-solr-heatmap).

to install *solr_wrapper* i ran  `gem install solr_wrapper`, however when i run `solr_wrapper` i can't find in solr the **default-core**.

what is wrong ?

Comment: Where should a default core be created? Solr doesn't create one by default in its standard installation

Comment: in [package.json](https://github.com/mejackreed/leaflet-solr-heatmap/blob/master/package.json) look at scripts ;curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/default-core/update?commit=true' --data-binary @fixtures/data.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'"  i m getting an error there

Comment: do i need to create it by myself ?

Comment: Yes, you have to create that core yourself if the install script didn't do it for you.